# Show that if $E$ is a Hilbert space and $x_n, x \in E$, then $\|x_n - x\|^2 = \|x_n\|^2 - 2\langle x_n, x \rangle + \|x\|^2$.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

> Show that if $E$ is a Hilbert space and $x_n, x \in E$, then $\|x_n - x\|^2 = \|x_n\|^2 - 2\langle x_n, x \rangle + \|x\|^2$.

I'm trying to verify this equality using the definition of the inner product, but I keep getting stuck. We know that $$\|x_n-x\|^2 = \langle x_n-x, x_n-x\rangle$$ and since the inner product has the property $\langle u+v,w \rangle =\langle u,w \rangle + \langle v,w \rangle$ using this $$\|x_n-x\|^2 = \langle x_n-x, x_n-x\rangle = \langle x_n, x_n-x\rangle - \langle x, x_n-x\rangle$$

but I cannot proceed from here since the first components are not sums anymore. How can one go further from this step?

Comment: An inner product being symmetrical/hermitian, you also have the same kind of formula on the second components.

Comment: Presumably you are dealing with a Hilbert space over $\mathbb{R}$